# Drupal 7 build pager

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, pager

I am trying to build a pager in a node list. Here is a piece of my code : 
`$nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);

```
$current_page = pager_default_initialize(count($nodes), 12);

$chunks = array_chunk($nodes,12, TRUE);

$build['pager'] = array(
  '#theme'  => 'pager',
  '#quantity' => count($nodes),
  '#weight' => 100
);`
```

There is just a little problem with this : I have a lot of nodes and it displays (page : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 etc to 150) What I actualy want is a pager like this (Page : 1 2 3 4 5 ...).

So the pager should not display 150 digits but only 5 with '...' at the end to show that there is more than 5 pages.

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the [theme_pager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager/7) in your template file. Or you could register your own theme with [hook_theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7), create the theme function and pass the new theme name in the render array like `'#theme'  => 'my_pager',`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for your time. I find the solution. I miss a ',' and thats why it did not displayed the pager when adding the '#quantity' in the theme array.